# Changes made to .properties file do not reflect in java

Tags: java, eclipse, tcpclient, properties-file

I have written a TCP Client program which calls the properties file and takes the values from there. When I run the TCPClient for the first time, it runs properly and sends all the data values of server.properties file to the server, but as soon as I try to add one more data "data4" to server.properties file my project gets a "x" mark and the changes made in server.properties file don't reflect and I get Error: cannot find or load class TCPClient.
I tried to create a new project, still the same, the changes made to properties file do not reflect. Can someone kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
public class TCPClient {

    private static Socket socket;

    public String getPropertyValues() throws IOException{

        String result="";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "server.properties";

        InputStream  inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

        prop.load(inputStream);

        try
        {
            String host = prop.getProperty("host");
            System.out.println(host);
            int port = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("port"));
            System.out.println(port);
            String data = prop.getProperty("data");
            System.out.println(data);

            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);  

            String sendMessage = data;
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Closing the socket
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        TCPClient properties = new TCPClient();
        properties.getPropertyValues();

    }
}
```

I have a properties file by name server.properties

```
data = data1
       data2
       data3

port = 3035
host = localhost
```

When ever I make change to the data field of this properties file and save, the project turns with a "x" mark and when I try to run the TCPClient program using Run as-->JavaApplication, I get the pop up as

Errors exist in required project

Test

Proceed with Launch?

Comment: This error occurs when class file is not found in the classpath , if you have already added the same in your classpath , then try cleaning your project once in eclipse .

Comment: Hi Neeraj, thank you for the comment. How do I add the class file in the classpath in eclipse. It would be of great help. I also have one more question, if this error is resolved will the changes made to properties file will reflect??

Comment: Are you using eclipse ?

Comment: yes Neeraj.. I am using eclipse Juno

Comment: ***[Here is how you set classpath in eclipse !](http://www.ehow.com/how_4784820_set-classpath-eclipse.html)***

Comment: Hi Neeraj.. still the same error.. Error: Could not find or load main class test.conn.tcp.TCPClient